# Como pesquisar um caractere em um conjunto de strings javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algoritmo-de-busca

Possuo um conjunto com determinadas strings, trata-se de um vetor, preciso que sejam feitas pesquisas por caracteres neste conjunto.

Caso:

- Seja `V` meu conjunto de strings contemplado por: `["ana", "paula", "cris", "voa", "karmanguia"];`
- Seja `P` a minha pesquisa, desejo que seja verificado no conjunto `V` a ocorrência de P nessas strings.

Desejo que retorne a confirmação da ocorrência de tal caractere e onde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const V = ["ana", "paula", "cris", "voa", "karmanguia"];
const P = 'a';

const res = V.reduce((found, string, i) => {
  const stringHasLetter = string.includes(P); // para saber se essa string tem a letra pretendida
  if (!stringHasLetter) return found;
  // para saber quais as posições da letra dentro da string
  const letterPositions = string.split('').map(
    (l, idx) => l == P && idx
  ).filter(nr => typeof nr == 'number').join(', ')
  return found.concat({
    vIndex: i,
    letterPositions: letterPositions
  });
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

A ideia é procurar em cada string e retornar os resultados em cada string também.

Comment: Obrigado e Parabéns Sergio, justamente o que preciso está aí!